# Ошибка загрузки пустого скетча на Arduino Leonardo Eth

Tags: arduino

При попытке загрузки пустого скетча на Arduino Leonardo Eth возникает ошибка:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:132)
at processing.app.debug.Compiler.upload(Compiler.java:166)
at processing.app.Sketch.upload(Sketch.java:1167)
at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1141)
at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1113)
at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Ошибка создания последовательного порта "COM4"
at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:92)
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:121)
... 6 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM4; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:86)
... 7 more
```

Так же, при подключенной ардуинке, при попытки открыть Монитор последовательного порта возникает ошибка:

```
Ошибка открытия последовательного порта "COM4" (Port busy)
```

Драйвера все переустанавливал. Номер порта менял. Ничего не помогает, идей как почить нету.

Comment: А оно точно на этом порту? Вытащить USB-кабель и вновь подключить и потом выбрать порт заново пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал :( Порт выбран правильно, в диспетчере задач проверял. И если порт не тот стоит, то ошибка другая совсем.

Comment: такая же проблема
пытаюсь порт открыть. проверте может порт используется другой прошраммой

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте при отправке скетча нажать на кнопку сброса на Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Если плата не оригинал,  возможно вы не установили драйвер usb конвертера CH340G.  Или плата указана не верно.